# Android: how run simple background loop

Tags: android, multithreading, loops, background

Hej, I'm trying to create an app that runs on a main thread, but also has a background loop running (to check for a connection).

I just want to call a certain function onCreate, and that function should run in the background...I've tried with the code below, but doesn't seem to work...any suggestions?

```
    void doStuffBackground()
    { 
     Thread testingForBluetooth = new Thread()
     {
      public void run()
      {
       try
       {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {

         writeTerminal('x');
         sleep(100);

        }

       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
        Log.e("Threading", e.toString());
       }
       finally
       {
        finish();
       }
      }
      };

      }

    }
```

But again...not working?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

You never started the thread.
Anyway if you need a background task, you could also try a service.

Comment: yup! Thanx, I'm not the threading kinda guy, but I need to learn them. And made this rookie mistake! Seems to be working fine now ;-) Thanx